# What are the gain and bias parameters used to control actuators?

Tags: control, dynamics, mujoco

When I read the [Mujoco official document](https://mujoco.readthedocs.io/en/latest/computation/index.html#actuation-model), the following paragraph raises my confusion:

> Different settings of the gain and bias parameters can be used to
> model direct force control as well as position and velocity servos -in
> which case the control/activation has the meaning of reference
> position or velocity.

Since I'm new to dynamics, I'm not quite understanding what the gain and bias parameters mean and how they affect the control process? A clear explanation would be a massive help.

Besides, are there any recommended materials to further dive into these parameters and the different control processes.

Thanks!